# How can I execute $string = if();?

Tags: php

So I'm trying rather simple thing.
But getting an error:

*(syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)*

My code:

```
<?php $string = if(  $_GET["category"] == '' ) {echo 'empty'}   ;   
echo $string; ?>
```

I guess I'm making a mistake somewhere along the lines.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I downvoted this question because it has nothing to do with wordpress, so keep that in mind. See [how to ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand what is the best way to ask questions.

Comment: This isn't a WordPress question, it's a basic PHP language question, those go on stackoverflow. Otherwise, if we translate this into pseudocode/prose/english we get: "set the string variaable to if the category is '' then echo empty", which doesn't make sense. A more literal version makes more sense: "if the category is '', print empty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options to assign that value into `$string` but ill show two

First using regular `if`

```
$string = '';

if (!empty($_GET['category']) {
    $string = $_GET['category'];
}
```

Second using ternary operator

```
$string = !empty($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : '';
```

When working with data that you receive from outer sources, for example, inputs, url etc... its always best to validate and sanitize it.

For the sake of keeping this answer clean ill only include the function that is used for validation/sanitization of `$_GET` or `$_POST` [filter_input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: thanks for your help!